# Using regex to delete part of string python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I am trying to clean a column of data to remove any characters inside of parenthesis (including the space in front of the parenthesis and the parenthesis themselves).  My attempt is causing every line containing a match to my regex to be completely replaced.

Here is what I have tried:

```
df['Col Name']=df['Col Name'].replace(r'\s\(.*\)','')
```

Sample string: Auburn (Auburn University)

Output using code above: None

Desired output: Auburn

Comment: I think this will make the trick: `re.sub('\s\(.+\)', '', s)` (beign `s` the string that you have`

Comment: I think we need to see more of your code because your regex works fine for me.  df['Col Name']=df['Col Name'].replace(r'\s\(.*\)','', regex=True)

Comment: Go Tigers! War Eagle! You need to use the `.str` accessor in your command. `df['Col Name'] = df['Col Name'].str.replace(r'\s\(.*\)','')`

Comment: As pointed out by @clockwatcher, the way the code is written in the example, it must include the `regex=True` parameter. Otherwise include the `.str` accessor, as I mentioned in the previous comment.